# Как в папке src создать папку fonts

Tags: javascript

Я создаю папку src и когда я в папке src создаю папку fonts(даже любую папку) у мен папка fonts встаёт справа папки src, а я хочу чтоб папка fonts была в папке src.(программа visual studio)

Comment: А зачем тут тег javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так наверное:

let dirpath = "./src/fonts"

fs.mkdirSync(dirpath, { recursive: true })